# Is there a semantic (code) behind the color of review-queue-indicator in the top-bar

Tags: support, review, top-bar

Until yesterday the review queue indicator was always orange like:

[image]

But yesterday it was dark red (unfortunately no screenshot).

Is there color-code (semantic behind the color not CSS/HTML stuff) for the indicator?

Comment: No, no color code. It was just changed to make it more legible (the white text on maroon on black background wasn't easy to read).

Comment: @Oded: Thanks for quick response. What did you mean with "changed"?. Today it is organge.

Comment: @Micha - we were trying a few different colors.

Comment: @Oded: Ah ok. Kind of open-heart operation. Red was nice inconspicuous ;-). Maybe you can add your comment as answer for accepting.

Comment: @bjb568: What did you mean? The "type of red" is not so interesting for me.

Comment: @bjb568: My question is not about css. Maybe color-code is a misinterpreted. I was more interested if there is a "semantic" behind the color.

Comment: @Gilles: from my point of view no duplicate but good additional informations.